# How to find song in MPMusicPlayerController by song and artist name

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

Say you want a user to type something into a text field, and then MPMusicPlayerController finds a song with that text and plays it. Is that possible? How do you search MPMusicPlayerController with certain words?

If this is not possible, is it possible for someone to play a song on one device and get details about that song and play the same one on another device?

I've tried the following code, but `MPMediaItem` doesn't contain the string of the song name. It just has random numbers and letters (the id).

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray *songs = [query items];
NSUInteger indexOfTheObject = [songs indexOfObject: @"Volcano"];
MPMediaItem *track = [songs objectAtIndex:indexOfTheObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a song, but not by using MPMusicPlayerController. You want to make an MPMediaQuery to explore what's in the user's music library.

> MPMediaItem doesn't contain the string of the song name

Well, the problem there is that your last line is utter nonsense:

```
MPMediaItem *track = [songs containsObject:self.songName];
```

An MPMediaItem has *properties*, one of which is the name of the song (MPMediaItemPropertyTitle). Either filter your query by property (i.e., an MPMediaPropertyPredicate) or fetch a lot of songs (maybe all of them) and examine the properties of those songs.

Comment: How do I use MPMediaQuery to find a song with a certain name and artist? Or is it possible to find a song by it's id (and the id of that song is the same on every device)?

Comment: Look, you can't keep expanding the question. I've answered the question as far as it went. Stop moving the goal posts. Anyway, I'm not going to teach you the whole of MPMediaQuery and MPMediaItem here! I've already explained it to you here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch29.html#_exploring_the_music_library

Comment: I'm not expanding the question. I was always asking how to play certain song based on a certain string.

Comment: And I think I told you. Look harder at the MPMediaItem docs. Look at the link I gave you.